# jQuery selector to select the value of a hidden field on changing the value of a drop down list within the same cell of a item template of Grid View

Tags: jquery, gridview, selector

I'm using a Grid View with columns as shown below:

```
<Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="CheckPointID" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" DataField="Description" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Response">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" CssClass="ChkResp" TabIndex="0" runat="server">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" TabIndex="0" CssClass="ChkResp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="mycalc" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnNextCPLogic" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
```

Now, I want to find the value of the hidden field within the Template Field(Header Text: Response) on changing the value of the Drop Down within the same cell. I've tried with the below sample jquery code but with no success.
Here's the same jquery code to get the value:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".ChkResp").change(function () {
            var nextlogic = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(2)').find("[id*='hdnNextCPLogic']").text();
```

But the above nextlogic variable shows empty. Please help!

Comment: Try `val()` instead of `text()`. If that doesn't work provide the resulting html because i don't know asp.

Comment: Yup, Thank you very much Wilmer.. That worked